# Magneto 2.1.9 upgrade to 2.2.2 Getting Error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, upgrade, magento2.2.2

- We are trying to upgrade a Magento 2.1.9 site to Magento 2.2.2 Getting Error .. 
  " Can anyone help me "

**Upgrade Commands**
 - composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 --no-update
**Then execute this all commands**
 - composer update
 - rm -rf var/di var/generation
 - php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 - php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Error Image message  on this link [enter link description here](https://ibb.co/Y045H9g)

**[Exception]                                                                                                                                                                                                  Warning: Declaration of Bss\MultiStoreViewPricingCatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\RuleAdmin::getRulePrices(DateTime $date, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productIds, $storeId = NULL) should be compatible w

  ith Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule::getRulePrices(DateTimeInterface $date, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productIds) in /var/www/html/app/code/Bss/MultiStoreViewPricingCatalogRule/Model/Res

  ourceModel/RuleAdmin.php on line 106**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the method declaration [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.9/app/code/Magento/CatalogRule/Model/ResourceModel/Rule.php#L182) (2.1.9) and [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.2/app/code/Magento/CatalogRule/Model/ResourceModel/Rule.php#L182) (2.2.2), you will see the difference that the older version uses `\DateTime` type for parameter named `$date`, but the newer version uses `\DateTimeInterface` type.

You have 2 options to fix the error:

1. upgrade your `Multiple Store View Pricing` module
2. edit the method declaration from `Bss\MultiStoreViewPricingCatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\RuleAdmin::getRulePrices(\DateTime $date, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productIds, $storeId = NULL)` to `Bss\MultiStoreViewPricingCatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\RuleAdmin::getRulePrices(\DateTimeInterface $date, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productIds)`

Comment: Dear, 
how to upgrade your Multiple Store View Pricing module?

Comment: Please you can support me on this 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/288211/magneto-2-2-2-upgrade-to-2-3-2-getting-error