# Magneto 2.2.2 upgrade to 2.3.2 Getting Error

Tags: magento2, php, upgrade, magento2.2.2, magento2.3.2

We are trying to upgrade a Magento 2.2.2 site to Magento 2.3.2, when executing `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` we get the error...

> Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 72.5 MiBPHP Fatal error:
>       Declaration of Bss\MultiStoreViewPricing\Model\Quote\Item\Collection::_assignProducts() 
>       must be compatible with Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\Collection::_assignProducts(): 
>       Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\Collection
>        in /var/www/html/app/code/Bss/MultiStoreViewPricing/Model/Quote/Item/Collection.php on line 124

[image]

Comment: Welcome, the issue is the extension your using is only compatible with magento 2.1 you need to upgrade it to the 2.2 version before running setup upgrade

Comment: i upgrade from 2.2.2 to 2.3.2

Comment: You may need to upgrade the module still as there are a number of new changes when it comes to custom modules which are not met in the 2.2 version you have installed. had similar issue with another extension yesterday

Comment: i run this command  bin/magento setup:upgrade  
before this stept  up upgrade the module

Comment: disable the BSS module and the setup will allow you to compelte the upgrade then you need to upgrade the BSS module before you can reactivate it

Comment: please could . you please provide me with steps for that

Comment: bin/magento module:disable Bss_MultiStoreViewPricing

Comment: Dear Dava, i did it now but still same error as per photo https://ibb.co/fHNPdC8

Comment: if you have disabled it run rm -rf var/cache/ var/di/ generation/ var/view_processed then run bin/magento setup:upgrade and finally run your compilation

Comment: I did it .. but unfortunately still same problem .. :( i think the problem there 
https://ibb.co/BN8MtnL

Comment: You need to module compatible working with Magento 232 after error not generate....

Comment: How module compatible  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what I have explained in your previous question, you have 2 options to fix the error:

1. upgrade your `Multiple Store View Pricing` module, or
2. edit the method declaration from `Bss\MultiStoreViewPricing\Model\Quote\Item\Collection::_assignProducts()` to `Bss\MultiStoreViewPricing\Model\Quote\Item\Collection::_assignProducts(): parent`

Comment: Dear Rendy
could you please review the code in this path:/var/www/html/app/code/Bss/MultiStoreViewPricing/Model/Quote/Item/Collection.php
check attached https://i.ibb.co/bBSms3n/2019-09-10-141531.png

Comment: which line i edit it